# What is needed/must be done to set up VPN connection to Windows Server programatically

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-server-2022

I have fresh installation Windows Server 2022. (In fact default installation of Virtual Private Server)

I want to set up it as VPN server without external SW. Then Windows 10 and 11 clients can connect to it. Also want to do the setup it programmatically it is repeatable.
I understand I can use methods from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remoteaccess/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

But there is long list of methods as it would be a long study for just this single case.
What is necessary to create the VPN server:

- Where client can connect to for Windows 10 and 11 without addition SW nor 3rd party SW.
- Is secure (does not use outdated protocols)

So far I have found. To install the needed feature it's needed (not sure if all three)

```
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
Install-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementTool
Install-WindowsFeature Routing -IncludeManagementTools
```

But what next is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

According to the article
[How to Set Up a VPN Server on Windows Server 2022](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/web-hosting/windows/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-windows-server-2022/),
you need to do exactly what you have found:

```
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
Install-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementTools
Install-WindowsFeature Routing -IncludeManagementTools
```

But you will also need to configure the installed software, so
read the following sections in the article:

- Step 3: Set Up Routing and Remote Access
- Step 4: Configure the VPN Properties
- Step 5: Configuring NAT Properties
- Step 6: Restart Routing and Remote Access
- Step 7: Configure Windows Firewall
- Step 8: Create VPN User
- Step 9: Connecting VPN Clients
- Step 10: Monitor your VPN Server

Comment: Would be great to have script also for the steps 3 - 10. AL least nice to have the steps, thank you. The goal of this question is to create the VPN server the "Configuration as Code" way (program or script). So it can be stored, versioned and used on another/backup machine without lot of clicking nor error.